# PHP iconv from utf-8 to windows-1252 with no special characters

Tags: php, iconv, windows-1252

I'm trying to encode a file contents like this:

```
$f_file = fopen("dreams.txt", "w");  
$string = "Los sueños se cumplen.";    
$string_encoded = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $string ), 'Windows-1252//TRANSLIT', $string );
fwrite($f_file, $string_encoded);
fclose($f_file);
```

If *$string* include a special character such as "ñ" or "á", the file is saved as Windows-1252 encoding but if *$string* does not include them, the file is encoded as UTF-8. I need the file with Windows-1252 encoding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A genuinely important question: what makes you claim that it's "encoded as UTF-8"? What are you using to check that?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text and NotePad++ to open the file. The encoding is shown there.

Comment: Thank you for the information, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans!

Comment: let me just turn that into an answer, because that's basically what it was.

Comment: "The encoding is shown there": To be clear, the encoding shown is one of dozens of encodings it _could_ be. The actual encoding is the encoding you chose when you caused the file to be written.

Answer (score 2):

The first 127 characters used in ASCII, ANSI (ISO-8859-1), Windows-1252, and UTF8 are all the same, so it's impossible to tell what "the" encoding is just by looking at a document with only characters from that set: they are all equally applicable.

Modern editors will see this and go "it's 2018 so I'm going to tell you it's UTF8", and they won't even be wrong: until you add those special characters, all these encoding schemes are interchangeable. It's not until you introduce higher bytecode characters that you will have to be explicit about what the encoding is supposed to be again.

Comment: Thank you for the info!

Comment: but remember to upvote answers that are useful, and accept answers that solve your problem. It's what allows stackoverflow to surface answers for people who search for help.